# Parse docx and ignore icons

Tags: java

I need to extract the list of all the words from a docx document, first I am doing that to make a string with all the words :

```
String newTxt = consultantId.toString();
if (filePath.contains("docx")){
   wordCounter.writeDocxToTxt(newTxt,wordCounter.parseDOCX(filePath));
}else if (filePath.contains("doc")){
   wordCounter.writeDocxToTxt(newTxt,wordCounter.parseDOC(filePath));
}
        
public String parseDOCX(String fileNameorFilePath )
    {
        try {
            XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(fileNameorFilePath));
            XWPFWordExtractor xwpfWordExtractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(docx);
            return xwpfWordExtractor.getText();
        }
        catch ( Exception error )
        {
            throw  new RuntimeException(error);
        }
    }

public void writeDocxToTxt(String newTxtName, String parsedDocx) throws Exception
    {
       BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(newTxtName)));
       bw.write(parsedDocx);
       if(bw!=null)
          bw.close();
    }
```

It works, I am getting a string with every words. But I don't want to get any character like phone icon below :

[image]

Is it possible to ignore icons ? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It could be from a font wingdings or such, but it seems you are lucky and it is a Unicode symbol.

```
String s = "\u260E"; // Black telephone
s = s.replaceAll("\\p{So}", " ");
```

Where `So` stands for *other symbols*. See javadocs of [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).